# vscode javascript does not recommend member function before complete the function name

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am vscode and javascript beginner.

When I write code like below,

```js
const title = document.querySelector("#title");
const hasClass = title.classList.contains("sth");
```

vscode does not recommend the member function "contains" before I complete the code.

Is there any shortcut or plug-in for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Working for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMtID.png

Comment: @MoshFeu Thank you for your reply. Does is still show you "contains" when you only write "c"?

Comment: Yes. It does...